# HtmlDocument.Save (HtmlAgilityPack) outputs incomplete document

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

We are using `HtmlAgilityPack` to save HTML ... the output is being trimmed, do not understand why.

The code we are using to create the export:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

string html = "<head>";

html += "<title>Page Title</title>";      
html += "<style>" + style + "</style>";
html += "</head><body>";
html += body; // string is not very long
html += "<script>" + js + "</script>";   
html += "</body>";

FileStream sw = new FileStream(html_file, FileMode.Create);
doc.LoadHtml(html);
doc.Save(sw);
sw.Close();
```

The exported file `body` is trimmed. What are we doing wrong?

The full string is pretty small and straight forward, it contains no scripts, special characters, none of that sort... the export is trimmed in the middle of the "Additional Charges" title at the second partial right after the title...

```
<div class="page-body">
                    <div class="top-title">1.Bill Summary <small style="font-size:14px;">1/2</small></div>
                    <div class="title" string="Device">
                        Period And Contract Information
                    </div>
                    <table class="partial">
                        <tr><td class="property">Maximum Half Hourly Demand:</td><td class="value">47,000 KWh</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Minimum Monthly Load Factor:</td><td class="value">57.2%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Actual Maximum Demand:</td><td class="value">40,843 KWh</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Actual Load Factor:</td><td class="value">69.2%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Period-to-date availability</td><td class="value">95.8%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Contract Discount</td><td class="value">0.00%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Contract Discount - Peak</td><td class="value">0.00%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Contract Discount - Shoulder</td><td class="value">0.00%</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Contract Discount - Off Peak</td><td class="value">0.00%</td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="title">
                        Bill Summary
                    </div>
                    <table class="partial">
                        <tr><td class="property">Energy Consumption</td><td class="value">7,072,662.46 ILS</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Fixed Fee to BB</td><td class="value">5,698.48 ILS</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Power Factor Fee to BB</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Other Fees to BB</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Min. Monthly Quantity charge</td><td class="value">66,791,095.60 ILS</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Additional Charges</td><td class="value">0.00 ILS</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Interest on Arrears</td><td class="value">0.00 ILS</td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="title total">
                        <span style="display: inline-block;width: 280px;">Total Bill</span><b>7,078</b>
                    </div>
                    <table class="partial">
                        <tr><td class="property">Monthly Discount</td><td class="value">371</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="property">Bill For Energy</td><td class="value">7,444</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of `body` and the trimmed result - that is the most essensial part of question.

Comment: i believe it is doing exactly what it should do, the input string of HTML is already trimmed (i.e. no new lines, tabs etc -not sure what the body is here), so why do you expect the agility pack to do the formatting for you?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to **reproduce the problem**. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should double check if the `FileStream` flushes the contents when it's closed. Try calling `Flush` before `Close`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have updated the question

Comment: @Krishna I have added input string... it is not trimmed, when it is exported it is trimmed

Comment: It does not trim anything when I run the code. What are the contents of `style` and `js` variables?

PS. what do you mean by trimmed? Are not all contents in the file or are spaces/new lines removed? Be aware that html variable concatenation (as done by you) results in one long line of HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which versions of .NET/HtmlAgilityPack you are using. I was able to reproduce it on .NET 4.0/HtmlAgilityPack 1.3.0.0 but not sure if these are correct versions.

Anyways, it looks to be some sort of HtmlAgilityPack bug with creating `StreamWriter` without setting `AutoFlush` to true. Thus it closes the stream writer without flushing it.

Good thing is that you can pass it your own `StreamWriter` instead of `Stream`.

Your code adjusted based on the results I got:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

string html = "<head>";

html += "<title>Page Title</title>";      
html += "<style>" + style + "</style>";
html += "</head><body>";
html += body; // string is not very long
html += "<script>" + js + "</script>";   
html += "</body>";

doc.LoadHtml(html);
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(html_file, FileMode.Create))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true }) {
    doc.Save(sw);
    // You don't need to Close the stream by yourself, Dispose() will do the work
    // sw.Close();
}
```

As a note, that I couldn't reproduce it on latest versions of .NET/HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: You have to have some experience in stackoverflow to know that this type of answers is what its all about. this answer is amazing. thanks! its working.

Comment: please upvote this question, its currently under zero, and I think this is relevant. also, if you can edit the title for something you think is more suiting... because the current title is very genreal